# Torus Action on Fan of Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dual-cone

Given a fan $\Sigma$ and suppose the corresponding toric variety $X_{\Sigma}$ is invariant under the action of a subgroup of the torus. Does this imply any sort of invariance of the fan? Or, more generally, does the action of the torus on $X_\Sigma$ induce an action of the torus on $\Sigma$?